# varnishncsa missing flags shown in docs

Tags: varnish

Installed version of varnish is 4.1.1 and os is CentOS7.x

varnish version:

```
varnishd -V
varnishd (varnish-4.1.1 revision 66bb824)
Copyright (c) 2006 Verdens Gang AS
Copyright (c) 2006-2015 Varnish Software AS
```

While trying to create some nice logs for varnish, using the varnishncsa tool, i found some flags and fields that i wanted to make use of.
But while trying to use said flags( -b -c ) and some fields( Varnish:side ) the tool complains about them not being available and halts execution.

Example:

```
varnishncsa -b ...
varnishncsa: invalid option -- 'b'
```

As seen on docs varnish [4.0](https://varnish-cache.org/docs/4.0/reference/varnishncsa.html) does not have these flags and fields available while [4.1](https://varnish-cache.org/docs/4.1/reference/varnishncsa.html) does.

The VCL that starts with varnishd is declaring a `VCL 4.0;` at the start. Any chance this has to do with it(i highly doubt that but you never know)? Changing this value to 4.1 or 4.1.1 makes the varnishd fail.

Upgrading varnish to 6.x is a no go from the dev side. But based on docs this should be working right away, unless i am missing something.

So how do i make these flags and fields available to me? What am i missing?

Answer (score 1):

All versions of Varnish 4 and Varnish 5 are end-of-life and no longer receive any updates. As you can see on http://varnish-cache.org/releases/index.html only the following versions of Varnish are supported:

- Varnish 6.5
- Varnish 6.6
- Varnish 6.0 LTS

If you have a look at the news section on http://varnish-cache.org, there have been a number of security vulnerabilities that have been fixed in recent versions of Varnish.

If upgrading from Varnish 4.0 to Varnish 6.0 LTS is not possible, I'm afraid you have far bigger problems than the `varnishncsa` problem you're reporting here.

I **strongly** encourage you to upgrade to Varnish 6.0 LTS. Try running a Varnish 6 instance on a separate machine and test the compatibility of your VCL file.

If anything comes up, I'll be glad to assist you in migrating your VCL file.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I do realize the security issues but the devs will not allow it just yet. It is on our plans since i have been pushing hard to keep software up to date. Other than that let me add that building varnish 4.1.11 from sources actually works as expected and varnishnsca have all the options available. Installing from packages does not although the version reported is the same but another revision code.

Answer (score 0):

building varnish 4.1.11 from sources actually works as expected and varnishnsca have all the options available. Installing from packages does not although the version reported is the same but another revision code.

As @Thijs Feryn mentioned it is not suggested to use unsupported versions on production but if anyone is facing the same issue on centos with this then try building from sources.

Comment: I installed Varnish 4.1 using packages on an Ubuntu Trusty server through https://packagecloud.io/varnishcache/varnish41 and I experienced no problems what so ever. Again: please use Varnish 6. But if you have no other options, the 4.1 official packages do the job just fine.